# constructor initialization with super()

Tags: java

I have a abstract class with a constructor "A" and want to use it in the constructor "B" of a child class with super(). However, I am forced to use super() in "B" on the first line:

```
public class B extends A {

    // constructor B
    public B(String name){
       // cannot have this on the first line
       int age = 18;
       // constructor "A" of abstract class
       super(name, age);
    }

}
```

How can I pass the age in the super constructor if I create the age in this "B"-constructor?

Comment: can you be more specific?

Comment: "if I create the age in this "B"-constructor" why you are not passing it as param to B(). If its fixed for all obj why not static class field ?

Comment: `super(name,age)` shoud be the first instruction in your constructor

Comment: Why don't you then create another constructor say `public B(int age){this.age = age}` and then call the `super(name, age)` from the other constructor?

Comment: because there is no one calling B(int age). the "age" should be calculated "privately" whithin the B-class. I can do something like super(name,getAgeAfterCalculation()), which is ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`super` must always be the first statement in a constructor of a derived class.

You basically have two options:

**a) Set your `age` directly inside the `super` call:**

```
public B(String name){
    super(name, 18);
}
```

You can also make other (simple) calculations or calls to (static) methods inline.

**b) Use a static factory method:**

```
public static B create(String name) {
    int age = 18;
    return new B(name, age);
}

private B(String name, int age){
    super(name, age);
}
```

This method provides more freedom (as you can now write statements before calling the constructor of B), but does not work if B is abstract as well.

Instead of calling the constructor of B (`new B("myName")`) you would then call the static `create` method (`B.create("myName")`).

Comment: Perfect. I cannot use solution a) with inline (because of some calculations which must be made before I can call the super()-constructor. But the solution of b) is perfect. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You may inline the code inside the constructor like this:

```
public B(String name) {
    super(name, 18);
}
```